# name 'ColumnDataSource' is not defined

Tags: python, bokeh, nameerror

I'm trying to run a python code with bokeh plots.

```
import itertools
import bokeh 
from bokeh import *
  source0 = ColumnDataSource(data={'x' : x1 ,'y=' : y1,})
  p1 = p.line(x = 'x',y = 'y',source = source0))
```

But while running this is gives the error in the title

> NameError: name 'ColumnDataSource' is not defined

Bokeh version (bokeh 1.0.2)
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: I have defined p as p = figure(plot_height=700,plot_width=1500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to directly import `ColumnDataSource` with

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it worked. But this was never a problem before. Do you know why did this happen now? I've worked with bokeh earlier but never faced this problem.

Comment: Maybe you were correctly importing the other functions before? I cannot say without seeing your other scripts. Please consider accepting the answer if it answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm facing the issue of "name 'figure' is not defined" when i define "p = figure(plot_height=700,plot_width=1500) ". Maybe i have installed bokeh incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

'bokeh' in `models` module you should import it from `bokeh.models` or from `bokeh` but use it as `bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource`

```
import itertools
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource 
    source0 = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': x1, 'y' : y1})
    p1 = p.line(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = source0))
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks. But the thing is i'm still facing a few error, like now it says that "name 'figure' is not defined" when i define "p = figure(plot_height=700,plot_width=1500) "

Comment: what package do you use with `figure` module?